# Debian 6.0.10 on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, debian-squeeze

I have a vendor supplied appliance that was developed for V-Sphere, that I am trying to convert to run on HyperV.  So far, I have converted the v-Sphere virtual Hard drive to a HyperV one, and have gotten it to boot correctly.

The appliance is built on Debian Squeeze version 6.0.10, so it does not have native support for the 'normal' network adapter that HyperV uses, so I setup a legacy network adapter, and have gotten the appliance to recognize it as a network adapter with an IP address (Static, not DHCP).

As it sits right now, I can ping the appliance's IP address from itself, both by address, and local loopback, but nothing else.  I can't get to the host server, or another machine on the same virtual switch, and nothing from outside the appliance can ping it either.

I am able to eliminate the HyperV virtual switch as the issue, as other virtual machines on the same switch are able to communicate without issue.

Some snippets off of my server that may be helpfull:

```
:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination  Gateway       Genmask        Flags  Metric Ref   Use  Iface
172.20.1.0   *             255.255.255.0  U      0      0     0    eth3
default      172.20.1.251  0.0.0.0        UG     0      0     0    eth3
```

.

```
:~# ifconfig
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:15:5d:01:74:06
          inet addr:172.20.1.229
          Bcast:172.20.1.255
          Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:3152 errors:0 dropped:131898 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:96 errors:509 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:7000
          RX bytes:1389454 (1.3MiB) TX bytes:12231 (11.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:9 Base address:0xec00

lo        Link Encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
          RX packets:246326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:246326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:89094448 (84.9MiB) TX bytes:89094448 (84.9MiB)
```

.

```
:~#lspci 
###Omitted for the sake of brevity###
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 211140[FasterNet] (rev 20)
```

.

```
:~#cat /etc/network/interfaces
###Comments omitted for brevity###
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
        address 172.20.1.229
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 172.20.1.0
        broadcast 172.20.1.255
        gateway 172.20.1.251
        dns-nameservers 172.20.1.242
```

.
Regardless of the address, I get the same output.

```
:~# ping 172.20.1.251
PING 172.20.1.251 (172.20.1.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.20.1.229 icmp=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What would cause this behavior, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: What happened to your `ifconfig` output? It looks rather...strange.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did have to manually re-type it, no internet, no GUI, no putty, no copy/paste, but that is pretty much how it looks on the screen.